# kendo config in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i dont know how use kendo in asp.net core project

I added js and css files to my project
and installed Telerik on my computer and referenced the dll files

I'm trying to use the upload file component and this error occurred:

'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no accessible extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

my project is asp.net core 3.1 and there is not any web.config file

```
 <div class="demo-section k-content">
       @(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("files").HtmlAttributes(new { aria_label = "files" }))
       <p style="padding-top: 1em; text-align: right">
         <button type="submit" class="k-button k-primary">Submit</button>
       </p>
 </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your _ViewImports.cshtml file in your MVC project Views folder, and add the following lines to it:

```
@addTagHelper *, Kendo.Mvc
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
```

If that doesn't resolve it, have a look at https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/first-steps